# How to Split date into intervals in initials dates

Tags: php

I want to split date into intervals.My code is splitting the dates in 5 months which i have given value in interval.But its taking the random 5 months.I want to split date in initially 5 months.

```
$startdate='2019-11-13';
$enddate='2020-08-14';
$parts='5';

function splitDates($min, $max, $parts, $output = "Y-m-d") {

    $dataCollection[] = date($output, strtotime($min));

    $diff = (strtotime($max) - strtotime($min)) / $parts;
    // echo $diff;
    $convert = strtotime($min) + $diff;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $parts; $i++) {
        $dataCollection[] = date($output, $convert);
        $convert += $diff;
    }
    $dataCollection[] = date($output, strtotime($max));
    return $dataCollection;
}

$dates = splitDates($startdate, $enddate,$parts);

foreach ($dates as $value) {
    $d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $value);
    $date=$d['year'].'-'.$d['month'].'-'.'15';
    print_r($date);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2019-11-15  2020-1-15  2020-3-15  2020-4-15  2020-6-15  2020-8-15
```

Please guide me for solution.

Comment: The code is dividing the interval by 5, but your comment seems to say you want the interval to be 5 months.  Can you include what you want the output to be.

Comment: 2019-11-15  2019-12-15  2020-1-15  2020-2-15  2020-3-15    i want this output

Comment: @NigelRen is right either you get interval of every month between given dates or you will get the exact equal desired parts of dates as shown in your question.

Comment: Every data has interval of 2 month @WarishaIqbal

Comment: if you want the data month wise then you will get the approx 10 dates. in given range.

Comment: than what chnages do i made?

Comment: So you want the 15th of the five months after the start date? What output do you want if the end date falls within those five months?

Comment: So you want the 15th of the five months after the start date?   Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it more flexible and to allow the `splitDates()` function to do most of the work, this adds a `$day` parameter.  If you pass the `$day` value in - it will adjust the start date to the that day of the start month.

As the function now does all of the processing to set the right day, after calling the function you can just use the array directly rather than having to further process the dates...

```
$startdate='2019-11-13';
$enddate='2020-08-14';

function splitDates($min, $max, $parts, $day = null, $output = "Y-m-d") {
    $date = strtotime($min);
    if ( $day ) {
        $date = strtotime(date("Y-m", $date)."-".$day);
    }
    $endDate = strtotime($max);
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $parts && $date < $endDate; $i++ )   {
        $dataCollection[] = date($output, $date);
        $date = strtotime("+1 month", $date); 
    }
    return $dataCollection;
}

$dates = splitDates($startdate, $enddate, 5, 15);

print_r($dates);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-11-15
    [1] => 2019-12-15
    [2] => 2020-01-15
    [3] => 2020-02-15
    [4] => 2020-03-15
)
```

Comment: Your `splitDates()` function doesn't use the `$max` parameter. Why is it there? Also: In what way does this function still split dates? A more appropriate name would be better, something like `getUpcomingMonths()`. Then the `$min` parameter can be simply `$startDate`, the `$parts` can be `$months` and I would rename `$day` to `$dayOfMonth`. Remember, shorter names are nice, but not when at the expense of the readability of your code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, for the name - without knowing the true context of this method, how can we determine what it is actually doing, aren't you making assumptions purely based on this small part of code.  I have added some processing for the `$max` so that it doesn't generate months after that date.  You could also say that the DocBlock is missing - which would define the use and types of parameters, but I tend not to include these in SO examples.